# Getting all MP3 files on the external card

Tags: android, mp3, mediastore

What i'm trying to achieve is getting all the mp3 files'URL and Title in an arraylist to return it. All from the folder: /ext_card/Music/ and all subfolders.

the options i've explored all seem to get stuck, and all the answers i've looked up on the internet point to mediastore, but i have no idea how to use it

And don't give me the RTFM bullshit, because the explanations i've found for mediastore is retarded at best.

SO can anyone please help me out or give me an example of a simple working mediastore query for all mp3 files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227895/android-songs-fetching-from-sd-card, maybe?

Comment: I just have to say this..... I was searching for the kind of issue, and the sentence: `And don't give me the RTFM bullshit, because the explanations i've found for mediastore is retarded at best. ` made me laugh out loud. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Use this it will help you to get all MP3 Song from SD CARD

```
private static ArrayList<genericSongClass> songs = null;

public void BindAllSongs() {        
        /** Making custom drawable */
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
        final String[] projection = new String[] {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
                final String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE
                        + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

                try {
                    // the uri of the table that we want to query
                    Uri uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    // query the db
                    cursor = getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,
                            projection, selection, null, sortOrder);
                    if (cursor != null) {
                        songs = new ArrayList<genericSongClass>(cursor.getCount());
                        cursor.moveToFirst();                       
                        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) { 
                            GSC = new genericSongClass();
                            GSC.songTitle = cursor.getString(0);
                            GSC.songArtist = cursor.getString(1);   
                            GSC.songData = cursor.getString(2);
                            songs.add(GSC);
                            cursor.moveToNext();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                } finally {
                    if (cursor != null) {
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                }       

    }

public class genericSongClass {
        String songTitle = "";
        String songArtist = "";
        String songData = "";
        String isChecked = "false";
}
```

Comment: Your code will display all music files irrespective of format. How to get only .mp3 files?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a recursive way to do such thing,

```
getMp3s(Arraylist<File> list, File dir){
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for(File file : files){
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            getMp3s(list, file);
        }else{
            //add mp3s to list here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its gonna give you list of all files, then you have to filter it out.

Comment: your answer is not full, so I think, you should fill it with all necessary information or you shouldn't answer at all