# How to load songs from an SD Card

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am building a music player app. I want it to automatically load songs from my sdcard but it's not working.

To make it work, I have to declare a specific path, but its possible for someone else's phone to have a different music folder and thus a different path.

On these phones if I declare a path then my app will not be able to load their songs.

Is it possible for my app to auto-load all the songs on a user's sdcard?

My code is here..

```
public class SongManager {
//khai bao duong dan toi sdcard
public static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("sdcard/ZingMP3");
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
// khai bao contructor
public  SongManager()
{

}
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList()
{
    File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

     if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0)
         for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()))
     {
         HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
         song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0,(file.getName().length()-4)));
         song.put("songPath", file.getPath());
         songList.add(song);
     }

    return songList;



}
class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
    }
}

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227895/android-songs-fetching-from-sd-card?rq=1