# Fetch all audio file from sdcard and show in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mediaplayer

I want to show all the audio files in a list in my activity and on click on any of them want to play that particular song.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lis = new ArrayList<String>();


    file = new File("/sdcard/");
    File list[] = file.listFiles();

    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
    {
            lis.add(list[i].getName());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, lis);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: @Vishesh-just follow steps-http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

Comment: is there any other way or tutorial for that .

Comment: @Vishes-what is the problem with that tutorial example...

Comment: check for the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227895/android-songs-fetching-from-sd-card

Comment: i have to make a lot of changes into my code due to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the same method as in question just by checking the extension. Also, 2 important changes you should make are, An extra ArrayList for Absolute paths and use of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

I have global variables

```
ArrayList<String> msqlist;
File listFile[];
ArrayList<String> absolutepath;
```

Now, Here is my method:

```
public void walkdir(File dir) {
    String msqPattern = ".mp3";// Can include more strings for more extensions and check it.

    File[] listFile = dir.listFiles();

    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
              if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(msqPattern)){
                msqlist.add(listFile[i].getName());
                absolutepath.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());

              }
            }
        }
    }    }
```

Call the above method as,

```
walkdir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());//  For /mnt/sdcard
```

Now, you have `msqlist` to set into list view, and upon list item click: use `absolutepath.get(position)` to get it's full path.