# How to record a voice and sent it to server?

Tags: android, voice-recording, file-browser

I am a naive developer in Android. I want to design a simple application where on a button click, voice recording will start. On click of another button, recording will stop. Other screen displays whether I want to save audio, save and send audio and discard audio.

1. If I click on save, it saves audio in sd card somewhere.
2. If I click on save and send, it saves audio and sends it to my php server.
3. If I discard, it redirects me to first screen again.

I am maintaining a local file browser in application. I want that the saved audios will be displayed in that file browser's folder.

Please tell me how to link my local file browser so that I will be able to browse the saved audio files through my application itself.

Comment: are you planning to make you whole app in single question ? : D

Comment: No, I am able to save audio, discard audio. But I am not able to find a way to list that audio in my app file browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19680688/501483 try this answer , That will give you path of all Audio file in your system